# Inserindo caracter especial no view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tenho uma table HTML onde uma de suas `td` preciso inserir a seguinte informação:

```
<td>@item.OrderSend º</td>
```

Queria inserir desta forma:

```
<td>@item.OrderSendº</td>
```

Porém ao juntar o carácter º com a variável `OrderSendº` o compilador entende que o º faz parte do nome da variável

Como eu posso juntar esse carácter com o valor da variável?

A variável retorna valores inteiros, por exemplo 1, 2, 3.

A saída na *view* deveria ser: `1º`, mas esta saindo assim: `1 º`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `item.OrderSend` dentro de parênteses, assim o *razor* vai entender que o símbolo "**º**" não faz parte do nome da variável.

```
<td>@(item.OrderSend)º</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

Outra forma de fazer é usando `string.Concat`, para concatenar as strings.

```
<td>@string.Concat(item.OrderSend, "º")</td>
```